# Extending Entity Framework's Unit of Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement the `Unit of Work` into my project and have some quick questions. I'm using the class shown [by this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application):

So when I implement it and let's say I make the class Users a `GenericRepository`. What if there are some items that I want to add to the `Users` class but not part of the `GenericRepository`.

How Do I create another interface and use some type of inheritance so I still get the stuff from the `GenericRepository` along with the new functions I wanted.

I basically want to extend it.

```
public interface ICategoryRepository : IGenericRepository<Category>
{
    IEnumerable<LocalComicCategoriesModel> GetCategories();
    IEnumerable<LocalComicCategoriesModel> GetCategoriesByComicID(int comicid, bool appendCategories);
}

public class CategoryRepository : GenericRepository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
{
    new ComicEntities context;

    public CategoryRepository(ComicEntities context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;

    }

    public IEnumerable<LocalComicCategoriesModel> GetCategories()
    {
        return context.Categorys.Select(i => new LocalComicCategoriesModel { Id = i.Category_Id, Title = i.Name });
    }

    public IEnumerable<LocalComicCategoriesModel> GetCategoriesByComicID(int comicid, bool appendCategories)
    {
        if (appendCategories == true)
        {
            IEnumerable<LocalComicCategoriesModel> query = from tbcat in context.Categorys
                                                           join tbitem_cat in context.ComicCategorys.Where(i => i.Comic_Id == comicid)
                                                           on tbcat.Category_Id equals tbitem_cat.Category_Id into ct
                                                           from tbitem_cat in ct.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                           select new LocalComicCategoriesModel
                                                           {
                                                               Id = tbcat.Category_Id,
                                                               Title = tbcat.Name,
                                                               isChecked = tbitem_cat == null ? false : true
                                                           };

            return query;
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<LocalComicCategoriesModel> returnedCategories = from t in context.Categorys
                                                                        join v in context.ComicCategorys on t.Category_Id equals v.Category_Id
                                                                        where v.Comic_Id == comicid
                                                                        select new LocalComicCategoriesModel
                                                                        {
                                                                            Id = v.Category_Id,
                                                                            isChecked = true,
                                                                            Title = t.Name
                                                                        };

            return returnedCategories;
        }
    }
}
```

To which I recieve this error:

```
'Comics.Models.Category' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'Comics.DAL.Interfaces.GenericRepository<TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Comics.Models.Category' to 'Comics.DAL.Interfaces.IGenericRepository<Comics.Models.Category>'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets say for you have a base/generic repository interface that looks like this

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
 {
     IQueryable<T> All();
     IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);        
     T GetById(int id);

     // and the rest of your methods
 }
```

If you had a "normal" class you wanted to implement this generic repository for, you could do so like

`IRepository<MyClass> MyClassRepository`

Now, for classes that need additional functionality (like your `User` class), you make an additional repository like so:

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
    {
        IQueryable<User> AllAuthorized();
        IQueryable<User> AllConfirmed();
    }
```

Then to use it, inherit from your generic repository and have it implement your `IUserRepository` interface.

```
    public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
    {       
        public IQueryable<User> AllAuthorized()
        {
            // implement here
        }

        public IQueryable<User> AllConfirmed()
        {
           // implement here
        }
     }
```

Now instead of instantiating a `IRepository<User>`, you'll just use a `IUserRepository`

Comment: If you do not have a base repository class, then you have to implement all the methods in both the repository. May be that is why you are getting the exception?

Comment: @ImranRashid Here's the final error I'm getting: `'Comics.Models.Category' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'Comics.DAL.Interfaces.GenericRepository<TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Comics.Models.Category' to 'Comics.DAL.Interfaces.IGenericRepository<Comics.Models.Category>'.`

I posted my code.